# Python- If condition for a variable True, execute function assigning new variable until False

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, random, matching, shuffle

I've not ever encountered this type of situation in a Python for loop before.

I have a dictionary of `Names (key)` and `Regions (value)`. I want to match up each Name with two other names. The matched name cannot be themselves and reversing the elements is not a valid match `(1,2) = (2,1)`. I do not want people from the same Region to be matched together though (unless it becomes impossible).

```
dict = {
    "Tom":"Canada",
    "Jerry":"USA",
    "Peter":"USA",
    "Pan":"Canada",
    "Edgar":"France"
    }
```

desired possible output:
`[('Tom','Jerry'),('Tom','Peter'),('Jerry','Pan'),('Pan','Peter'),('Edgar','Peter'),('Edgar','Jerry')]`

Everyone appears twice, but Jerry and Peter appears more in order for Edgar to have 2 matches with Names from a different region (Jerry and Peter should be chosen randomly here)
`Count: Tom: 2, Jerry: 3, Peter: 3, Pan: 2, Edgar: 2`

My approach is to convert the names into a list, shuffle them, then create tuple pairs using zip in a custom function. After the function is complete. I use a  a `for` to check for pairings from the same region, if a same pairing region exists, then re-run the custom function. For some reason, when I print the results, I still see pairings between the same regions. What am I missing here?

```
    import random
    names=list(dict.keys())
    def pairing(x):
        random.shuffle(x)
        #each person is tupled twice, once with the neighbor on each side
        pairs = list(zip(x, x[1:]+x[:1]))
        return pairs

    pairs=pairing(names) #assigns variable from function to 'pairs'

    for matchup in pairs:
        if dict[matchup[0]]==dict[matchup[1]]:    
            break
            pairing(names)

    pairs=pairing(names)
    for matchup in pairs:
        print(matchup[0] ,dict[matchup[0]] , matchup[1] , dict[matchup[1]])
```

Just looking at it, something is clearly broken in the for loop, please help!

I've tried `while` rather than `if` in the for loop, but it did not work.

Comment: When you detect an invalid pairing - you simply `break` from the loop and go on with the program; the second call to `pairing()` is unreachable (and wouldn't do anything, anyway, since you throw the return value away).

Comment: When I set `pairs=pairing(names)` at 3rd last line, won't that capture the return value from the `for` loop?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that line.  What that does is make all your previous work meaningless, because you generated entirely new pairs and didn't check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
import random

dict={'your dictionary'}

#create function to pair names together
def pairing(x):
    random.shuffle(x)
    #each person is tupled twice, once with the neighbor on each side
    pairs = list(zip(x, x[1:]+x[:1]))
    for matchup in pairs:
        if dict[matchup[0]]==dict[matchup[1]]: #if someone's gym matches their opponent's gym in dictionary, re-run this function
            return pairing(x) 
    return pairs

pairs=pairing(names)
for matchup in pairs:
    print(matchup[0] ,dict[matchup[0]] , matchup[1] , dict[matchup[1]])
```

The trick is to `return pairing(x)` inside the custom function. This will return new pairings if any elements in the tuple share the same value in the dictionary. If inside the `if statement`, you go `pairing(x)` then `return pair`, it'll return the original tuple list which contains duplicates.